# Combinations problem for all possible combinations

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Ok, so the sample space of 3 coin flips has 8 outcomes:

hhh, hht, hth, htt, thh, tht, tth, ttt

If you can select any number (including 0) of outcomes to create an event, the total number of events is both:

1. 2^2^3 = 256
2. 8-choose-0 + 8-choose-1 + ... + 8-choose-8 = 256.

I understand why #2 above is correct, but how can you arrive at #1 above?  Is it NumberOfOutcomesPerCoinflip^???^NumberOfCoinFlips?  I can't quite figure it out.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both formulas count the number of subsets of a set of size $2^n$.

In the first formula each of the $2^n$ elements can either be "in" or "out" of the subset.  So there are $2$ possibilities for each of $2^n$ elements, giving a total of $2^{2^n}$ subsets.

The second formula sums over the number of subsets of size $i$, so it gives $$\sum_{i=0}^{2^n} \text{nr subsets of size } i=\sum_{i=0}^{2^n} \binom{2^n}{i}.$$

Comment: The second formula makes sense, but I don't understand what the 2^2^3 represents in the first formula.  3 I assume means 3 coin flips, but the other 2 2's, what do they each represent?

Comment: Oops, I misread that (I'm getting sleepy).  Basically, each of $2^n$ elements is either "in" or "out" of a subset.  So there's $2$ choices for each of $2^n$ elements.  (I added that to my answer.)

Comment: Ok, so if I have a 6 sided die, and roll it 3 times, the number of subsets is 2^6^3?  The beginning "2" will always be 2 because an element will either be in or out of a set?  Am I understanding correctly?  Thanks!

Comment: Yes, that's right.  However, it's probably simpler to describe the possible outcomes as a set $A$; in this case, there's $|A|=6^3$ possible outcomes and $2^{|A|}$ subsets of $A$.  The number of subsets being $2^{|A|}$ is true for arbitrary sets $A$.